# Can't override onCreateOptionMenu inside Inner class that extends View

Tags: android

I'm using Java to create View instead of XML. And in the inner class that extends View, I can't override `onCreateOptionMenu` and `onOptionSelected`. I've imported `android.view.Menu` and `android.view.View`. 
Why it doesn't work?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyGraphicView(this));
}

@Override // method doesn't override from its superclass
public class MyGraphicView extends View
{
    public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); // error occures here
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Drawing line");
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Drawing circle");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `onCreateOptionMenu` is method of `Activity` not `View`. Before moving to Technology please read Basics of Java.

Comment: @ADM @psikink You are right but I have added an answer and he doesn't need to create a class into `MainActivity`.
He can get direct through `OptionsMenu` and he need to learn about android developing at the **Android Official Site**

Comment: But I'm trying to setContentView by my inner class

Comment: @LuckyTuvshee Can you tell us why do you need to set the `contentView` by inner class ?

Comment: Um, It's just my course example and I followed but ended up asking here

Comment: Oh god, I am wrong, I thought if **onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected** are outside the inner class, it won't work. But it works, thanks

Comment: Okay, @ADM, I'll learn more from Android Official Site ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a new project for your case and it is working.

You don't need to create an extra class to have an `OptionsMenu`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Drawing line");
    menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Drawing circle");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how to call this on Inner class?

Comment: I understood, There's no need to call this on Inner class.

Comment: If this is working please make my answer as accepted. Glad to help you.
And it is better if you use `menu` with `xml`  because you have easier to use them for `selectedItems` then to have an action or something like this.